# Javascript regular expression replacement with grouping

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, grouping

I've got an input which consists of a number passed as a string, such as "12345678". Sometimes, this might contain leading or trailing white space. The number needs to be stripped of any white space and prefixed with an identifier so that it looks like "P12345678" - Simple?

I thought of using the following regular expression but I can't seem to get the replacement to work correctly:

```
input = input.replace(/^\s*(\d+)\s*$/,/P\1/);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `String.prototype.trim` in "modern" browsers: `input = 'P'+ input.trim();`

Comment: the second argument to replace is a string, not a regex

Comment: Look in to string.trim here, provided is also compatibility code for older browsers
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
input = input.replace(/^\s*(\d+)\s*$/, "P$1");
```